# Require to Import syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, google-translate, google-cloud-translate

Does anyone know the import syntax for this line of code:

```js
const { Translate } = require("@google-cloud/translate").v2;
```

I was thinking something like:

```js
import { Translate } from "@google-cloud/translate.v2"
```

but that doesnt work. any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Try using:

```js
import { v2 } from "@google-cloud/translate";
// use "v2.Translate"
```

or

```js
import { Translate } from "@google-cloud/translate/v2";
```

Comment: The second one looks better but didn't work

Comment: import {v2} from '@google-cloud/translate';
const translate = new v2.Translate();

Answer (score 0):

For my own project, using v7.2.1 of the library, I have this:

```
import { Translate } from "@google-cloud/translate/build/src/v2";
```

Answer (score 0):

2024:
i needed to do like this in Nodejs:

```
import { Translate } from "@google-cloud/translate/build/src/v2/index.js";
```